# "Overview" tab missing from Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I wish to add my local project to an online repo and Bitbucket's article says I'll need to start on the "overview" panel. 
[image]

I logged out then in, removed and created a new account and disabled adblock but to no avail. I'd like to require assistance to get it sorted out.

Comment: Did you read this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html ?

Comment: I don't have a Bitbucket server, just the free (2GB limited) online repo.

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud

Comment: Thanks, but right now I'm looking into SourceTree :D I posted a bug report to atlassian, if they write back and solve the issue, I'll post the result here.

Comment: Initialize project folder as a git repo... create project on bitbucket... push local to repository...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update, in the meantime I contacted Atlassian and they told me they are removing that button is all.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it back by going to Bitbucket settings > Bitbucket Labs > disable "New source browser experience".

This seems to be a mandatory step to subscribe to repos.